# Why upgrade from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

We have been using 12.04 LTS already for a couple of years but we are considering to move to the next LTS version which is 14.04. It was released on April 2014 I so was wondering how people consider this version.

Stable
Slower or faster
uses less/more resources
BTW we are considering the headless/server version of 14.04

Thanks

Comment: Now is a great time to consider switching distributions. See for instance [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Why you should not use it, at all](https://tim.siosm.fr/blog/2014/04/25/why-not-ubuntu-14.04-lts/)

Comment: @MichaelHampton But, but.. my DevOopses, they all love the Ubuntu!  How can I tell all those special snowflakes we're using something else???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the release notes and compare with the linux version you are using currently. If the differences makes sense to you you can switch .

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes